# Stop PHP escaping JSON string when writing to file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, escaping

I'm trying to save changes to a JSON file using JQuery and PHP, but it seems my PHP script is escaping the characters when it saves out the JSON, meaning I can't read it back in again.

I'm passing the JSON object ('family') to save.php using the following code:

```
function saveChanges() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "save.php",
         data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(family)
         },


         success: function(msg){
             console.log(data);
   }
 });
    }
```

Then save.php writes the JSON data to armstrong.json with the following code

```
<?php

$data = $_POST["data"];
echo $data;
$filename = 'armstrong.json';

if (is_writable($filename)) {
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, "w")) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, parse_json($data)) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }
echo "Success, wrote ($data) to file ($filename)";

fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}

?>
```

However the file is being written out as follows:

```
{\"title\":\"Armstrong\",\"description\":\"The Armstrong Family\",\"patriarchID\":\"id1\",\"latestID\":8,\"members\":[{\"name\":\"Grandad\",\"id\":\"id1\",\"children\":[\"id2\",\"id3\"]},{\"name\":\"Dad\",\"id\":\"id2\",\"children\":[\"id4\",\"id5\",\"id6\",\"id7\"]},{\"name\":\"Uncle\",\"id\":\"id3\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id4\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id5\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id6\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id7\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id8\"}]}{\"title\":\"Armstrong\",\"description\":\"The Armstrong Family\",\"patriarchID\":\"id1\",\"latestID\":9,\"members\":[{\"name\":\"Grandad\",\"id\":\"id1\",\"children\":[\"id2\",\"id3\"]},{\"name\":\"Dad\",\"id\":\"id2\",\"children\":[\"id4\",\"id5\",\"id6\",\"id7\"]},{\"name\":\"Uncle\",\"id\":\"id3\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id4\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id5\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id6\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id7\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id8\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id9\"}]}{\"title\":\"Armstrong\",\"description\":\"The Armstrong Family\",\"patriarchID\":\"id1\",\"latestID\":10,\"members\":[{\"name\":\"Grandad\",\"id\":\"id1\",\"children\":[\"id2\",\"id3\"]},{\"name\":\"Dad\",\"id\":\"id2\",\"children\":[\"id4\",\"id5\",\"id6\",\"id7\"]},{\"name\":\"Uncle\",\"id\":\"id3\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id4\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id5\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id6\"},{\"name\":\"Child\",\"id\":\"id7\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id8\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id9\"},{\"name\":\"a\",\"id\":\"id10\"}]}
```

Any ideas how I can stop it escaping the characters? The JSON file should look like this

```
{
            "title"         :   "Armstrong",
            "description"   :   "The Armstrong Family",
            "patriarchID"   :   "id1",
            "latestID"      :   7,
            "members"       :   [
                {
                    "name"  :   "Grandad",
                    "id"    :   "id1",
                    "children": ["id2","id3"]
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Dad",
                    "id":       "id2",
                    "children": ["id4","id5","id6","id7"]
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Uncle",
                    "id"    :   "id3"
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Child",
                    "id" :  "id4"
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Child",
                    "id"    :   "id5"
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Child",
                    "id"    :   "id6"
                },
                {
                    "name"  :   "Child",
                    "id"    :   "id7"
                }

            ]
}
```

Comment: looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417987/slash-appended-to-all-my-posts/7418026#7418026

Comment: What is `parse_json` in your php code? That's not a built in php function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled and the slashes already exist at the time you do `$data = $_POST['data']`.

See this answer: [Slash appended to all my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417987/slash-appended-to-all-my-posts/7418026#7418026)

BTW you could replace fopen/fwrite/fclose by [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that other question but it did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) turned on in your php.ini. You should turn them off. This would explain the escaping

EDIT - if you need to know more about magic quotes read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Magic quotes are bad, if you have access to your php.ini you should turn them off

Comment: Sounds interesting, how would I do that, and would it affect anything else?

Comment: if you need to know more about magic quotes [read here]http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. Magic quotes are bad, if you have access to your php.ini you should turn them off

Comment: That does seem to have been the problem. Looking into them now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to decode your json then encode for simple but ugly example:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
$json = json_encode(array($data));

echo $json;

?>
```